# How to remove thanks footnote mark from title only in headers in KOMA-Script?

Tags: header-footer, koma-script

I would like to remove `\thanks` footnote mark from `\title` only in headers in KOMA-Script.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\clearscrheadfoot
\chead[]{\mytitle}

\begin{document}
\title{Title\thanks{Thanks!}}

\makeatletter
\let\mytitle\@title
\makeatother

\maketitle

\newpage

Text

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can catch two birds with one stone:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\makeatletter
\xapptocmd\maketitle{%
  \begingroup\let\thanks\@gobble
  \protected@xdef\mytitle{\@title}%
  \endgroup
}{}{}
\makeatother

\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\clearscrheadfoot
\chead[]{\mytitle}

\begin{document}
\title{Title\thanks{Thanks!}}

\maketitle

\newpage

Text

\end{document}
```

In this way, `\maketitle` will define `\mytitle` as the title without `\thanks`, because the command has been temporarily defined to gobble its argument.

If you want to be able to define a running title, you can do

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\runningtitle}[1]{\gdef\@runtitle{#1}}
\xapptocmd\maketitle{%
  \@ifundefined{@runtitle}{%
    \begingroup\let\thanks\@gobble
    \protected@xdef\mytitle{\@title}%
    \endgroup}
    {\global\let\mytitle\@runtitle}%
}{}{}
\makeatother

\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\clearscrheadfoot
\chead[]{\mytitle}

\begin{document}
\title{Title\thanks{Thanks!}}
\runningtitle{Short}

\maketitle

\newpage

Text

\end{document}
```

So long as `\runningtitle` precedes `\maketitle`, you'll get what you want.

Comment: Thanks. Perfect. I also would like to be able to set the `mytitle` variable manually by a command like `\runtitle{}` just in case I would like to use a shorter title for headings. An idea how I would do this given the `\protected@xdef`?

Comment: @Daniel Added code for that.

Comment: Great. Unfortunately, I cannot up-vote further.

Answer (score 1):

Just define a new command `mytitle` to define the title without `\thanks`:

```
\newcommand{\mytitle}{Title of document}
```

Now you can use command `\mytitle` for the header and for the title in the title page you just use

```
\title{\mytitle\thanks{Thanks!}}
```

With the complete MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{scrpage2}

\newcommand{\mytitle}{Title of document}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\clearscrheadfoot
\chead[]{\mytitle}

\begin{document}
\title{\mytitle\thanks{Thanks!}}


\maketitle

\newpage

Text

\end{document}
```

you get the desired result for the title page

[image: title page]

and the second page

[image: second page]

Comment: Thanks. I guess a downside of this approach is that the `\thanks` must be at the end or the beginning. But I guess that is normally the case. Would be nice to have a command that just strips away the `\thanks` though.

Comment: Thanks. That's doable but a bit cumbersome.